# Federated Azure users can't log in to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: entra-id

We've just set up Azure AD and federated it with our G Suite system. I see the provisioned users from G Suite and can log in to Azure and Office with them, no problem.

I also have a Windows 10 Pro PC and have joined it to Azure. Users on our `onmicrosoft.com` domain can log in to the computer without a problem. Federated users on our real domain, as imported from Google, cannot.  It just says, "The user name or password is incorrect. Try again."

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is the output of `dregcmd /status`, if helpful:

````
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

             AzureAdJoined : YES
          EnterpriseJoined : NO
              DomainJoined : NO
               Device Name : DESKTOP-HGU3NIR

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device Details                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                  DeviceId : f4873935-0c29-46f1-ab19-09ede789fa92
                Thumbprint : 7874F6B739CD8E9C7562F8DFAC3487DE48E2782F
 DeviceCertificateValidity : [ 2020-09-01 18:35:09.000 UTC -- 2030-09-01 19:05:09.000 UTC ]
            KeyContainerId : d3bf6055-56ac-4cd1-9f1d-bc2203c26d44
               KeyProvider : Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider
              TpmProtected : YES
          DeviceAuthStatus : SUCCESS

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tenant Details                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                TenantName : translifeline.org
                  TenantId : 417bd5b1-b5ae-4bca-a87a-adadeb358522
                       Idp : login.windows.net
               AuthCodeUrl : https://login.microsoftonline.com/[ID]/oauth2/authorize
            AccessTokenUrl : https://login.microsoftonline.com/[ID]/oauth2/token
                    MdmUrl : 
                 MdmTouUrl : 
          MdmComplianceUrl : 
               SettingsUrl : 
            JoinSrvVersion : 2.0
                JoinSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/EnrollmentServer/device/
                 JoinSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
             KeySrvVersion : 1.0
                 KeySrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/EnrollmentServer/key/
                  KeySrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
        WebAuthNSrvVersion : 1.0
            WebAuthNSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/webauthn/[ID]/
             WebAuthNSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
    DeviceManagementSrvVer : 1.0
    DeviceManagementSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/manage/[ID]/
     DeviceManagementSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User State                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                    NgcSet : YES
                  NgcKeyId : {972D2D93-F29A-44D4-8B35-BD4C8F6BBF11}
                  CanReset : DestructiveOnly
           WorkplaceJoined : NO
             WamDefaultSet : YES
       WamDefaultAuthority : organizations
              WamDefaultId : https://login.microsoft.com
            WamDefaultGUID : {B16898C6-A148-4967-9171-64D755DA8520} (AzureAd)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SSO State                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                AzureAdPrt : YES
      AzureAdPrtUpdateTime : 2020-09-01 19:21:01.000 UTC
      AzureAdPrtExpiryTime : 2020-09-15 19:21:00.000 UTC
       AzureAdPrtAuthority : https://login.microsoftonline.com/[ID]
             EnterprisePrt : NO
    EnterprisePrtAuthority : 

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Diagnostic Data                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

        AadRecoveryEnabled : NO
    Executing Account Name : AzureAD\Chris'TestAccount, christest@translifelineorg.onmicrosoft.com
               KeySignTest : PASSED

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IE Proxy Config for Current User                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

      Auto Detect Settings : YES
    Auto-Configuration URL : 
         Proxy Server List : 
         Proxy Bypass List : 

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| WinHttp Default Proxy Config                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

               Access Type : DIRECT

For more information, please visit https://www.microsoft.com/aadjerrors```
````

Comment: According to Google and Microsoft support, G Suite doesn't support WS-Fed or WS-Trust, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The log above only shows that the device is indeed joined to Azure AD, it does not show what is happening during the user authentication process.

From the description of your setup/error, it seems like the SAML federation with Google is not correctly enabled, reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/faq#q-why-do-i-get-a-username-or-password-is-incorrect-message-for-a-device-i-just-joined-to-azure-ad

To check your SAML federation with Google: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on#configure_saml_settings

To rule out any issues with the devices registration, use this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Hybrid-Azure-AD-Joined-0ea7e778

For more basic troubleshooting for the AAD joined devices: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/troubleshoot-hybrid-join-windows-current

Hope this helps.