# Google Federated Azure users can't log in to Windows 10

Tags: g-suite, entra-id, federated

We've just set up Azure AD and federated it with our G Suite system. I see the provisioned users from G Suite and can log in to Azure and Office with them, no problem.

I also have a Windows 10 Pro PC and have joined it to Azure. Users on our onmicrosoft.com domain can log in to the computer without a problem. Federated users on our real domain, as imported from Google, cannot. It just says, "The user name or password is incorrect. Try again."

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds very similar to something I answered way back: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032329/federated-azure-users-cant-log-in-to-windows-10-pro